# Python 3: Exec doesn't work when function is called from menu item in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, exec

I am working on the final Run function for my Python text editor, and it seems that I can't run the code.

Here is my code:

```
self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

self.runMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, font=("Consolas", 10))
self.runMenu.add_command(label="Run", command=self.run)
self.menu.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=self.runMenu)

def run(self):
    exec("print('sdf')")
```

And nothing prints out. This is strange because when I define the function and run it in the shell, it actually does work properly.

Comment: Can you post a bigger code snippet? Currently it appears as if your code is defined inside of a class due to `self` references, however your snippet doesn't reflect that.

Comment: why would you call `exec` instead of directly calling `print`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I redefined the function later in my code which made it do absolutely nothing.